# What's wrong with this Recyclerview Logic?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, picasso, universal-image-loader

In my app, I am saving URL links(**around 4000 url's having images in an Arraylist** ) from a URL and displaying them in recyclerview... It is working **but taking alot of time to display images.** I have used *Picasso and Universal Image Loader library* with different alterations but cannot remove the lag/delay in image loading. The first 20,30 images are shown nicely and then the image loading process slows down to what i can say is unbearable for an app user. Can some one explain me what I need to do or what I need to avoid in this code logic in order to overcome this problem. Below is my AsyncTask class

AsyncTask class:

```
     String linkHref; 
     Context context;
     ArrayList<String> linkArray = new ArrayList<>();
     final IAsyncTaskListener listener;
     String url = "http://www.**************";

    public Description(Context context, IAsyncTaskListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements links = document.getElementsByTag("a");
            for (Element eachLink : links) {
                linkHref = eachLink.attr("href");
                String baseLink = "http://www.*********.com";
                baseLink = baseLink.concat(linkHref);
                linkArray.add(baseLink);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        this.listener.onCompleted(linkArray);

    }

    public interface IAsyncTaskListener {
        void onCompleted(ArrayList<String> linkArray);
    }
 }
```

And onCompleted() Implementation is :

```
 @Override
 public void onCompleted(ArrayList<String> linkArray) {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
//linkArray.remove(0);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this);
recyclerViewAdapter.setDataArray(linkArray);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

And my Adapter class is :

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> linkArray;
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setDataArray(ArrayList<String> linkArray) {
        this.linkArray = linkArray;


    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {


//        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
//        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
//                .cacheOnDisc(true)                .build();
//
//
////download and display image from url
//        imageLoader.displayImage(String.valueOf(linkArray.get(position)), holder.image1, options);


        Picasso.with(context).load(linkArray.get(position)).into(holder.image1);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return linkArray.size();
    }


    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image1;

        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image1 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }
    }
```

Any help/guidance/suggestion would be highly appreciated.